# "Invalid use of New Keyword" in VBA using old com object written in c++

Tags: c++, vba, com

I've scoured the web and stackoverflow for this answer but can't find anything.  I have written a com object in C++ (for the fist time) that works when used in vbscript and through `cocreateinstance` in an executable file.  So I decided to see if it would work in Excel VBA.

So I went into "References" and located my object there.  Checked the box and started coding away.  The following is the VBA code.

```
Function doCos(x As Double) As Double
  Dim t As SimpleLib.IMath
  Set t = New SimpleLib.IMath ' <- "Invalid use of New keyword" error here
  doCos = t.Cos(x)
End Function
```

Intellisense recognizes my object in the `Dim` statement, but it does not appear when I use a `Set` statement.  Obviously I am using a registered type library or else intellisense wouldn't work at all.  Again, the com object can be used in vbscript or an executable, but for some reason can't be used, at least with the new keyword, in VBA.

Does anyone have an idea what may be wrong, or what may have to be added to the com object?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using CreateObject instead of New?

Comment: You are trying to create an interface instead of an object.  Not valid of course.

Comment: Yes.  CreateObject works.  But I'd like to know how to expose it to a `New` call.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a Class object?

Comment: @HansPassant  Can you elaborate?  I was under the impression that COM objects are used extensively in VBA.  Bear in mind I'm very new to everything COM.  The documentation of this old technology is awful.

Comment: I can't, the only thing is obvious is that your code is wrong.  You have a named coclass in your COM server, that's the one you want to create an instance of.  Perhaps it is named "Math", that would be a logical choice, but that's just a guess.

Comment: You have a class that implements IMath? that's what you `set` to

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define a coclass in the IDL that includes the interface needed (IMath in my case).  NOTE:  That the `[default]` interface is hidden by default.  So I simply defined `interface IUnknown` as the default.  After compiling with MIDL a type library is generated which one should register with regtlibv12.exe.

I then included an additional IF statement in `DllGetClassObject` like `if (rclsid == CLSID_Math)` where `CLSID_Math` is corresponds to the CLSID defined in the file automatically generated from MIDL.  All I did was copy and paste the body of the IF statement from `if ( rclsid == IID_IMath )`, updated the DLLRegisterServer and DLLUnRegisterServer functions, recompiled the project, and regsvr32.exe.

So the following works now.

```
Function docos(x As Double) As Double
  Dim a As SimpleLib.IMath
  Set a = New SimpleLib.Math
  docos = a.Cos(x)
End Function
```

Thanks to Hans for the tip about the coclass.  Learned something new and useful.